# how to deploy a specific dll using VSTS?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I want to deploy a specific dll using Team Foundation Server but i do not know how to deploy a specific dll.
please help me

Comment: You should be more specific or the moderators will close your question. See the help for ideas. What you mean with deploy, what TFS version, you use Deploy Groups, the target is a single server, many servers, client, what DLL is this (C, .Net 2, .Net 4, .NetCore) etc

Comment: I'm using TFS 2017 ,when i process build using VSTS then its create so many DLLs,but i need to deploy only 1 dll on multiple server ,i dont want to deploy all DLLs ,i am using .Net 4.6

Answer (score 0):

You could add a [Copy Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=vsts) task before publishing/deploying. In this task, copy the dll you need to a target folder and publish or deploy it:

[image]